# Is "as" a preposition or an adverb?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, adverbs

> *"We can even shut out everything external to us, and concentrate on an internal dialogue, **as** when we are lost in thought."*

Is "as" a preposition or an adverb?  Thanks.

Comment: *None!* Seems to be *conjunction* to me.

Comment: If it is a conjuction, then why is there not a subject or verb.   Is it an adverb?

Comment: I think it is a preposition.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the page https://www.grammarly.com/blog/like-vs-as/ is that it attempts to reduce this to "a simple rule" and so over-simplifies. Also, the distiction seems to be being gradually dropped in actual usage.

In addition to comparing things, "as" can be sued to mean "in the role of".

> It is important to remember that he was speaking as a judge, not an advocate.

Here "like" would be wrong, or would at best change the meaning significantly.  The point here is that "he"  was speaking **in the role of** a judge, not in some other role. He was not speaking **like** a judge, he **was** a judge. Similarly, "behaving as an X" can mean "acting in the role of an X."

Now as to the example:

> We can even shut out everything external to us, and concentrate on an internal dialogue, as when we are lost in thought.

I think this is actually more natural, and flows better, then the version using "like". In such constructions "as when"  means "in the way in which things happen when" or it may be giving an example, and be seen as short for "such as when"

> I often lose track of time, as when I am reading a technical paper.

"reading a technical paper" is one of several possible examples of when the speaker loses track of time

Answer (score 0):

I believe your example sentence is ungrammatical. I think it should be:

> We can even shut out everything external to us and concentrate on an internal dialogue, ***like*** when we are lost in thought.

***Like*** is used as a preposition, telling where, when or how the noun in the sentence is doing whatever it may be doing.

When to you use "like" as opposed to "as" can be confusing. This page sums it up nicely: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/like-vs-as/

Answer (score 0):

*"As"* in *"as when"* as used in the sentence is a Preposition. *"as when"* is best regarded as Compound Preposition.

> He found her lovely and attractive, as when he had last seen her; but, since that time, what changes had taken place, and how might her heart have altered! (1827)

[The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language Page No. 626]